# Swipe for custom function in RecyclerView inside Tabbed Layout of Fragments

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have a RecyclerView inside a Fragment which is one screen in a tabbed layout.
The RecyclerView represents a day's activity and I wish to show the day before or day after with a swipe.
I can catch the SwipeLeft because it's the first tab in the TabbedLayout. But SwipeRight moves to the next tab.

I have implemented the ItemTouchHelper.Callback and it seems fine, except that I cannot stop the swipe action of the TabbedLayout from displaying the next tab.

To be clear I wish to prevent the natural swipe behaviour of a Tabbed Layout for this one Tab, and do something within the Tab.

Answer (score 0):

The approach (for swipe right == forward) is to let control go to the next fragment and then return to fragment 0.

```
float x1, x2, y1, y2, dx, dy;
void moveEventProcessor(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            x1 = motionEvent.getX();
            break;
        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
            x2 = motionEvent.getX();
            dx = x2-x1;
            Logd(String.format("x1 = %f x2 = %f dx = %f",x1,x2,dx ));

            if (dx > 0){
                executeBackButton();
            }else{
                // maybe delay a couple of seconds
                executeForwardButton();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

this is triggered by an OnTouch event captured...

```
 mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent   motionEvent) {
            Logd(String.format("in On Touch Listener...event = %s",motionEvent.toString()));
            moveEventProcessor( motionEvent);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

In the Main Activity in onPageSelected(int Position) when the second page is selected I use a LocalBroadcast to tell page 1 that it should go back to page 0.

```
public BroadcastReceiver localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logd("in broadcast receiver for GoChartScreen");
        MainActivity.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0); //
        return;...
```